# Displaying contact name not working

Tags: android, android-contacts

The below mentioned code is no displaying any name on `Logcat`

```
Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, 
            null, null, null, null);

    while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
        name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
        Log.d("name : ", ""+name);
    }

    cursor.close();
```

From the code above am trying to display contact name's on Logcat. But the while loop is not executing. Is there any mistake in my coding.

How can this be solved?

Comment: try `DatabaseUtils#dumpCursor`

Comment: @pskink : The result shows `V/Cursor Object(10317): >>>>> Dumping cursor android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner@17caf583`

Comment: and what is between >>>>> and <<<<< ?

Comment: @pskink :- `Dumping cursor android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner@17caf583`

Comment: so your cursor is empty log it with cursor.getCount()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do `cursor.moveToFirst()` inside while loop.. When u r checking for `cursor.moveToNext()` the cursor will move to the next position and the data there will b null.. So u shud move the cursor to first position n then print the name.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Cursor phones = cr.query(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null,
                null, null);
        while (phones.moveToNext()) {
            ContactSynRequestcontacts data = new ContactSynRequestcontacts();
            String name = phones
                    .getString(phones
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String phoneNumber = phones
                    .getString(phones
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            data.setName(name);
            data.setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
            userContactList.add(data);
        }
        phones.close();// close cursor

You also need to add premission 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
in manifest.
```